# Where does Ramchal's idea of circulating calendar come from?

Tags: sources-mekorot, calendar, ramchal

I am in search of any source preceding Derech Hashem, 4:7:6 (Sefaria Translation):

> חגיגת החגים הזמניים: ואולם מלבד הקידוש הזה הנשער במדריגותיו כפי מדריגת קדושת הימים יש עוד ענינים פרטיים מיוחדים לכל זמן מזמנים אלה כפי ענינו. ושרש כלם הוא סדר שסדרה החכמה העליונה שכל תיקון שנתקן ואור גדול שהאיר בזמן מהזמנים בשוב תקופת הזמן ההוא יאיר אור מעין האור הראשון ותחודש תולדת התיקון ההוא במי שקבלו. והנה עפ״ז נצטוינו בחג בכל הענינים שנצטוינו לזכר יציאת מצרים כי בהיות התיקון ההוא תיקון גדול מאד שנתקנו בו וכמש״ל הוקבע שבשוב תקופת הזמן ההוא יאיר עלינו אור מעין האור שהאיר אז ותחודש בנו תולדת אותו התיקון וע״כ נתחייב באותם הענינים כלם. ועד״ז חג השבועות למתן התורה וחג הסוכות לענין ענני הכבוד אעפ״י שאינו אותו הזמן בפרט אלא שקבעה התורה חג זה לזכרון ענין זה וכמ״ש כי בסוכות הושבתי וכו׳‎. וכן חנוכה וכן פורים ועד״ז היו כל ימי מגלת תענית אלא שנתבטלו מפני שלא היו ישראל יכולים לעמוד בהם ונפטרו מהיות עושים זכר להם והתעוררות לאור המאיר. ועתה נבאר המצות האלה בפ״ע:
>
> Celebration of the periodic holidays: But besides this holiness that was determined about their levels according to the level of the holiness of these days, **there are other specific attributes to each time period according to its content. And the root of them all is the order arranged by the Supreme Wisdom, such that the refinement refined and the great light that shone at a particular time return at that period of the year to shine light similar to the first light and have the effect of the refinement be renewed in the one that received it [originally].** So see that, according to this, we were commanded on the holiday [of Passover] about all the things that we are commanded in memory of the exodus from Egypt. For since that refinement was a very great refinement that happened to us - as we wrote above - **it was embedded that upon the return of that period of the year, a light similar to the light that shone then, shine; and that the effect of that refinement be renewed in us.** Therefore we were commanded in all of those matters. And in the same manner, the holiday of Pentecost (Shavuot) for the giving of the Torah; and the holiday of Tabernacles (Sukkot) for the clouds of glory. Even though [the latter] is not specifically at the same time, the Torah fixed this holiday for the memory of that matter, as it is stated (Leviticus 23:43), "that I placed them in huts, etc." And likewise Chanukah, and likewise Purim [have observances tied to the events they commemorate). And in this same manner were all the days [listed] in the Scroll of Fasting, but they were annulled since Israel was not able to keep them. So they were exempted from memorializing them and from the arousal of the [corresponding] shining light. And now we will explain these commandments on their own.

Comment: Sir Downvoter, did you make sure to read the quotation I have presented above? The Ramchal is a universally accepted Jewish figure. Moreover, since this is a Jewish [Ramchal] site, and my question [source inquiry] is one which makes use of the official guidelines in asking questions, I have failed to understand properly your Downvote. -Dr. Shmuel

Comment: I didn't downvote,  but as is, I have know idea what you are asking. What are you calling circular? This is a very long quote. Perhaps bold the line you are inquiring about, or restating it so people know what to focus on? This seems interesting, but I just don't know.... Perhaps the downvoter felt the same. Remember, weakly worded and formatted questions and answers are downvoteable.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @user6591.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel It says by chanuka that they only made it the next year. The meforshim say they waited to see if they had the same 'light' as the year before.